# QML : Navigation between qml pages from design perception

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

We need to develop a QtQuick project, where we have about 100 screens.

I had tried to make a demo project for the navigation which has three screens on button click. I had used the concepts of 'States' in the navigation between the pages. Initially I tried the same using 'Loader' but loader was not able to retain the previous state of page, it was re-loading the entire page during the navigation.

Below is the code snippet of main.qml

```
// import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id:main_rectangle
    width: 360
    height: 640

    Page1{
        id:page1
    }

    Page2{
        id:page2
    }

    Page3{
        id:page3
    }

    states: [
        State {

            name: "page2"

            PropertyChanges { target: page3; visible:false; }
            PropertyChanges { target: page1; visible:false; }
            PropertyChanges { target: page2; visible:true; }
        },
        State {
            name: "page1"
            PropertyChanges { target: page3; visible:false; }
            PropertyChanges { target: page2; visible:false; }
            PropertyChanges { target: page1; visible:true; }
        },

        State {
            name: "page3"
            PropertyChanges { target: page1; visible:false; }
            PropertyChanges { target: page2; visible:false; }
            PropertyChanges { target: page3; visible:true; }
        }

    ]

}
```

This runs well with the small POC with three screens, but its not feasible to define states for 100 screens.

From designing aspect we concluded to make a C++ controller we controls the states, visibility of various pages.

Need suggestions how to implement the 'State' logic in C++.

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: Currently we are targeting Windows

Comment: I meant we are targeting desktop versions on Windows currently

Answer (score 7):

Here is the simplest solution in plain QML, using a configurable page list (like a model) + a Repeater + Loader items to not load everything at startup (lazy instanciation) and not destroy a page after hiding it (to not have to reload it if we come back to it) :

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: main_rectangle;
    width: 360;
    height: 640;

    // Put the name of the QML files containing your pages (without the '.qml')
    property variant pagesList  : [
        "Page1",
        "Page2",
        "Page3",
        "Page4",
        "Page5"
    ];

    // Set this property to another file name to change page
    property string  currentPage : "Page1";

    Repeater {
        model: pagesList;
        delegate: Loader {
            active: false;
            asynchronous: true;
            anchors.fill: parent;
            visible: (currentPage === modelData);
            source: "%1.qml".arg(modelData)
            onVisibleChanged:      { loadIfNotLoaded(); }
            Component.onCompleted: { loadIfNotLoaded(); }

            function loadIfNotLoaded () {
                // to load the file at first show
                if (visible && !active) {
                    active = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: To go further, you can replace the use of `visible` property with a custom one, let's say `shown`  that will be used together  with `scale` or `opacity` and some `Behavior {}` component to do nice page change transition...

Comment: And if  your page's QML  files aren't in the same folder, you will need to provide the relative path before the page file name in the array and in the `currentPage` property :
- if in a subfolder:  "folderName/fileName"
- if in a parent folder: "../folder/filename"
- eventually an absolute path, but not a very good idea !

Comment: Bootroo's answer won't compile in Quick 2. Here are the changes: `main_rectangle.currentPage` and `main_rectangle.pagesList`, looks like variables now scope. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use StackView from Qt Quick Components. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) is its documentation.

Comment: What I know PageStack is specifically for Symbian platform. Will it work on desktop platform on Windows OS?

Comment: If your navigation pattern looks like in the phone, I think it is possible to use it. In desktop Qt Quick components, which I downloaded now, I see only one "View Manager" - TabBar.

Comment: I can say from experience that the PageStack can definetly be a solution here.  However, it is not a very complicated control and you can always consider implementing your own.  Basically you create a parent object that has an array as a page stack and you use the QML dynamic object creation to create pages and push them onto the stack as needed.  I highly suggest looking into the code of the PageStack in the components. It is not very complicated at all, and my inspire you.