# How to access the QtObject inside the Loader inside a Repeater?

Tags: qt, qml

Let's say I have a `QtObject` loaded by a `Loader` which is embedded in a `Repeater` (which itself is attached to some arbitrary `ListModel`).

How would I access the properties and functions of the `QtObject`?

```
Repeater {
        id: repeater
        model: listModel
        Loader {
            sourceComponent: QtObject {
                   property int width: 100
                   property int height: 100

                   function foo() {console.log("bar")}
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you access the Loader using [`itemAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method) function and then the QtObject using [`item`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) property:

```
var loader = repeater.itemAt(index)
var qt_object = loader.item
console.log(qt_object)
```

Comment: I had tried exactly that, except I hadn't put it on a second line: `var fooBar = repeater.itemAt(index).item`. That seems to have been the crucial distinction, although I'm at a loss for why. What is happening differently between the two? And why does this one-liner approach fail here, but work in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20154777?

Comment: @KennSebesta It must be equivalent, I just wanted to be didactic in my answer.

Comment: Huh. I must have been making a subtle mistake elsewhere, then. Thanks for the rapid answer, it is tested and works.